# Is there a way to monitor the text selected by user in other apps in android

Tags: android

I know that user can share the selected text, copy the text into clipboard in order to pass the text to third party application.
But can that be simpler way such that user highlight the text (eg in browser) and then pass the selected text to my app?
If not, may be long click or some other gesture after selecting the text.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for would cause a major security hole so I highly doubt you can do that.
The application itself needs to send you the data (e.g. share intent etc), sending selected text could mean an app can snoop on the activities you do on other apps.

Comment: Thanks. But I don't think it is a security hole If I ask for user permission.